# Why can I not use dot notation while setting `maxlength` attribute to an `input`?

Tags: javascript, html, maxlength

I am using Firefox and I wanted to add dynamically created `input` to the document. I use the dot notation to set attributes.

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.placeholder = "Working";
input.maxlength = 4;
document.getElementById("add_here").appendChild(input)
```

However, I encountered a strange issue.
The `placeholder` attribute is correctly added, but the `maxlength` is not set.

I made a JSFiddle to prove it: https://jsfiddle.net/phc8fxba/

The only workaround I found is to use `.setAttribute(maxlength, 4)` but this is weird.

Why is dot notation not working here?

Comment: Note than `setAttribute()` it's not weird. It is a valid and standard method for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo, it should be:

```
input.maxLength = 4;
```

Comment: I did not think it was a typo issue as [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) write it without uppercase. Thank you.

Comment: @Delgan: one reason to use MDN as reference.

Answer (score 1):

The property is named `maxLength`, not `maxlength`:

```
input.maxLength = 4;
```

HTML attributes are not case sensetive, but JavaScript properties are.

Answer (score 1):

Change it with `input.maxLength = 4;`. Your command doesn't work because javascript supports camel case.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use setAttribute function to set maxlength and placeholder etc. Dot notation direct accessing to the attributes. Using getter or setter function is better.

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Working');
input.setAttribute('maxLength', 4);
```